# PHP 5.4: Getting Fully-qualified class name of an instance variable

Tags: php, oop, reflection

I know there is a static `class` field on PHP 5.5, but I have to stick to PHP 5.4. Is it possible to get the fully qualified class name from a variable?

Example:

```
namespace My\Awesome\Namespace

class Foo {

}
```

And somewhere else in the code:

```
public function bar() {
   $var = new \My\Awesome\Namespace\Foo();

   // maybe there's something like this??
   $fullClassName = get_qualified_classname($var);

   // outputs 'My\Awesome\Namespace\Foo'
   echo $fullClassName 
}
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.get-class.php#107964 So apparently `get_class()` does provide the namespace as well. Did you try that?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should be using [`get_class`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php)

If you are using namespaces this function will return the name of the class including the namespace, so watch out if your code does any checks for this.

```
namespace Shop; 

<?php 
class Foo 
{ 
  public function __construct() 
  { 
     echo "Foo"; 
  } 
} 

//Different file 

include('inc/Shop.class.php'); 

$test = new Shop\Foo(); 
echo get_class($test);//returns Shop\Foo
```

This is a direct copy paste example from [`here`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php#97164)

Answer (score 16):

I know this is an old question, but for people still finding this, I would suggest this approach:

```
namespace Foo;

class Bar
{
    public static function fqcn()
    {
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}

// Usage:
use Foo\Bar;
// ...
Bar::fqcn(); // Return a string of Foo\Bar
```

If using PHP 5.5, you can simply do this:

```
namespace Foo;

class Bar
{}

// Usage:
use Foo\Bar;
// ...
Bar::class; // Return a string of Foo\Bar
```

Hope this helps...

More info on ::class [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class).

Answer (score 7):

For developers using PHP 8.0 and above, you can now easily do this without `get_class`.

PHP8 introduced the support for `::class` on objects. Example:

```php
public function bar() {
   $var = new \My\Awesome\Namespace\Foo();

   echo $var::class;
}
```

Here's the [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/class_name_literal_on_object) for more info.